# Can't complete "No One Escapes Cidhna Mine" quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I killed Madanach just before exiting the mine and got the note from him. However, I did not **read** the note. I exited the mine and had a drawn-out, exhausting battle with the Forsworn whom I finally managed to kill after about 9-10 tries.

I then looked at the quest status and it require me to read the note from Madanach. I read the note. The next goal is to exit the Cidhna mine... which I cannot do, because when I get back to Cidhna mine, the quest marker points at the far end of the mine, which I cannot reach. There is Urzoga gra-Shugurz (the Orc prison warden) with a couple of Silver-Blood Guards. The place has no means to get to the prison cells (where the marker points to). There is a chain with a barred window in front, but there is no option to activate or pull the chain.

I'm stuck here. Can anyone tell me how to complete the quest?

Comment: Are you playing on PC?

Comment: @Joachim yes. I have finally reloaded the old saves and finished it in the simple manner by siding with the Forsworn and am done with it. It looked very attractive to get both of the corrupt parties kill each other, but oh well. I go on hunting sprees at times, with Lydia, on Forsworn settlements now ...

Answer (score 2):

The only step [it seems](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:No_One_Escapes_Cidhna_Mine#Two_Rewards) the quest requires at this point in order to be finished is speaking with Thonar Silver-Blood, who should actually be outside of the mines. If you are unable to find him, you can use some console commands if you're playing PC:

- Use `prid 198E6` to select [Thonar's reference ID](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thonar_Silver-Blood) in the console;
- Use `moveto player` to place him in front of you.
- Now talking to him should do the trick.

Note: the quest marker pointing to the unreachable exit out of the Cudhna mines could be explained by Thonar's position in-game, as he might theoretically be reached more easily by exiting the mines on the other side.